# Configuring SQL Replication subscriber to a publisher in a different DNS zone

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a server that I wish to set up a subscriber on, however the publisher lives on a different domain controller and is not in the primary DNS.

To access the server, a FQDN needs to be provided.
so `publisherServer` becomes `publisherServer.something.local`

when trying to add a subscription, I get the following error:

> SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Connections through a server alias, IP address, or any other alternate name are not supported. Specify the actual server name

How can I set up a subscription, when the server name `publisherServer` does not resolve from the server I wish to subscribe from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can set up the subscription if I add the server name and ip into the hosts file.

Not pretty, but it works.